# Libcurl HTTP GET request using a query string

Tags: c++, http, get, libcurl

I'm struggeling with doing a GET request passing a query string. Everytime I run it I get 410 gone response, I checked if the link got deleted but it's still accessible.

**My code:**

```
    CURLUcode rc;
    CURLU* url = curl_url();
    CURL* handle = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist* list = NULL;
    
    if (handle) {
        rc = curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_HOST, "www.example.com", 0);
        rc = curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_QUERY,"b=sashio", CURLU_APPENDQUERY);
        rc = curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_QUERY, "id=me_ZwNjBQRlZGL0AwR0ZQNjAQR1AQZ3At==", CURLU_APPENDQUERY);
        rc = curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_SCHEME, "http", 0);
        rc = curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_PATH, "/en/m.php?", 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_CURLU, url);

        list = curl_slist_append(list, "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);

        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");    
    }

    res = curl_easy_perform(handle);
```

**Verbose output :**

```
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 410 Gone
< Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2020 19:41:23 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE9
< Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Aug 2020 19:41:23 GMT
< Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Etag: "1804121564-00010031-BZGZ0AGt5BQt2AGD1ZQZ1AmV"
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=tp3mbkk7148cm989areejhhd90; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Length: 192
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
<
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: I putted the comma by mistake.

Comment: How did you check the link?

Comment: By browsing it.

Comment: @Max: And does the browser tell you the HTTP response code it received? Or did you just assume it was not 410 because you are seeing a web page?

Comment: The URL `http://www.example.com/en/m.php?b=sashio&id=me_ZwNjBQRlZGL0AwR0ZQNjAQR1AQZ3At==` gives me a HTTP 404 error code, not 410. I tested this both with CURL and with my browser.

Comment: What happens when you run curl from the command line, like this: `curl -Iv www.example.com/en/m.php?b=sashio&id=me_ZwNjBQRlZGL0AwR0ZQNjAQR1AQZ3At==`? I get a HTTP 404 response.

Comment: I don't know why it gives me 410 gone even if the content exists.

Comment: @Max: It is normal for web servers to return an an HTML page even in the case of an error. This is normally the page informing the user of an error.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `CURLUPART_QUERY` omit the `CURLU_APPENDQUERY` flag, since no query has been set yet? More importantly, the `?` between a path and a query is not part of the path (or query) itself, so it shouldn't be included explicitly in `CURLUPART_PATH` (or `CURLUPART_QUERY`)

Comment: When I access `http://www.example.com/en/m.php?b=sashio&id=me_ZwNjBQRlZGL0AwR0ZQNjAQR1AQZ3At==`, I get a 404.

Comment: @Max: This is very strange. I get `Server: ECS (dcb/7F81)` in the HTTP response from the server. However, in the HTTP response you posted, the server is identifying itself as an Apache server? Are you really using `www.example.com`?

Comment: www.example.com of course is just an example. I'm trying to get an email from my inbox.

Comment: Your browser is probably sending the server a session cookie in the HTTP request, so that it gets a different response from the server than libcurl.

Comment: I removed the `?` in the path end also removed the first `CURLU_APPENDQUERY` flag but it still gives me HTTP 410 error.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone specially @AndreasWenzel. **The browser was sending a cookie to the server** like AndreasWenzel said. So in the headers I added the cookie, now I receive a correct response.
Have a nice day!